# Why moving a std::string landed on a different address?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, move-semantics

I happened to find an interesting thing that I did not expected:

```
std::string c = "abc";
std::cout << static_cast<const void *>(c.c_str()) << std::endl;

std::string d;
d = std::move(c);
std::cout << static_cast<const void *>(d.c_str()) << std::endl;
```

I expected the two printed addresses to be the same because move on std::string should avoid copying from c to a different location in d, but directly use the address/pointer in c. However, it always gives two different addresses on my computer.

I run it on Mac, compiled by: `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o move`
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0

I believe my understanding on move is correct, and this idea works on std::vector. Did I miss anything, or std::string move is implemented differently?

```
std::string c = "abc";
std::cout << static_cast<const void *>(c.c_str()) << std::endl;

std::string d;
d = std::move(c);
std::cout << static_cast<const void *>(d.c_str()) << std::endl;
```

Shouldn't be it print two same addresses?

Comment: Small string optimization, look it up.

Comment: As @n.m. says, change `std::string c = "abc";` to `std::string c = "abc12345678901234567890";` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/13vEvcxqY

Comment: Turns out that copying `"abc"` is less work than allocating a buffer and copy the pointer. So even faster!

Comment: @BoP `std::move` implies that the value is taken from `c` and given to `d`. If the storage of `"abc"` required dynamic allocation, then the move would steal the existing storage from `c`. There is no case here where `std::move` would lead to an allocation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - To be able to steal the storage, these has to have been an allocation in the first place. In this case "abc" is smaller than a pointer, so copying it is the cheapest alternative. That was supposed to be my point - that moving isn't *always* the best option.

Comment: @BoP The reason `"abc"` is copied isn't because it is smaller than a pointer. It is because it is small enough to fit in the `std::string`'s own representation (which is much larger than a pointer) and that the implementation chose to use Small String Optimization. The point of it is to avoid the dynamic allocation, not to save copying a pointer during move. Even if you use a string that is much larger than a pointer, but small enough to fall within the platform's SSO limits, it will be copied even if it would be faster the copy a pointer.